# Blade component variables not rendered

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have used the Laravel `@component` statements successfully before in my project, but for some reason my variables aren't being rendered in the following case.

```
<div id="{{ $modalId }}" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">Add a user</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
@component('components.modal_bootstrap')
  @slot('modalId')
    {{ 'test' }}
  @endslot
@endcomponent
```

**Expected Result**

`test` is rendered as the id of the modal dialog.

**Actual Result**

`{{ $modalId }}` is the id of the modal dialog.

---

I have also tried and copy pasted the examples shown in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade, but the same problem persists. I think I'm missing something obvious, but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: this is a potentially silly question but does your file for the component end in .blade.php?

Comment: @AlecJoy Well this is embarrassing... I thought it was but it turned out it wasn't. You can post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the curly braces are being rendered out as-is it's usually a sign that the file extension is incorrect, make sure you file ends in .blade.php or it won't be parsed as a blade template